# global solution of an ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, analysis

I have this ODE
\begin{equation}
x'(t) = x(t) \ln^2 x(t) e^{\frac{1}{\ln x(t)}}
\end{equation}
and I would like to discuss global existence and uniqueness of its solution.

I was convinced that we do not have global existence and uniqueness beacuse it is impossible to find a K such that

\begin{equation}
\lvert  e^{\frac{1}{\ln x}} \biggl(     \ln^2 x + 2 \ln x -1 )\biggr)\rvert < K
\end{equation}

where the expression on the left is the firs partial derivative with respect to x of the dynamic $f(t,x) = x \ln^2(x) e^{\frac{1}{\ln x}} $

I was convinced of that since
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\frac{1}{\ln x}} \biggl(     \ln^2 x + 2 \ln x -1 )\biggr) = \infty
\end{equation}

However, there must be an error here; can you please explain me why?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Is $\ln^2(x) = \ln (x) \ln(x)$   on in your notation $\ln^2 x  = (\ln x) (\ln x)$ ?

Comment: yes it is the square of the logarithm

Comment: The solution is, if I see it right, $e^{-1/ln(x)}=t+c\iff \ln(x)=-\frac1{\ln(t+c)}\iff x(t)=e^{-1/\ln(t+c)}$. So there are some singularities that occur for finite $t$, and some finite boundaries for $t$.